# BLE device not showing up in Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device and want to access it from a web page using the Web Bluetooth API.

This works perfectly fine in Chrome on Windows (at least with current versions of Chrome and Windows) and even with the WebBLE App on iPadOS (since Safari won't support WebBluetooth).

But I have multiple Android devices running the current versions of Android (12) and Chrome (97), where in the browser device chooser, the device won't show up. Some other unknown devices show up, but my device does not.

What could be the reason just this one device does not show up and how could I gather more information about this situation?
It happens in the native browser dialog so my usual debugging steps don't work.

**Update:**
I have already checked with `chrome://bluetooth-internals`, and the result is the same. The device shows up on Chrome/Windows but not on Chrome/Android.

Now I also used `chrome://device-log` which on both Windows and Android shows only

> *Bluetooth Internals Page initiating Bluetooth discovery session*

*nRF Connect for Mobile* shows the device instantly, and it also shows up in the Android Bluetooth settings. Only Chrome Web Bluetooth doesn't show it.

**Update2:**
The `adb logcat` reveals the following line during Chrome Bluetooth discovery:

> V/BtGatt.GattService(19403): Skipping data matching denylist

What's that? Has Chrome its own denylist for bluetooth devices?

**Update3:**
Android has a denylist for BLE devices, which should not be applied if the App (Chrome) has ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions. But Samsung seems to apply the denylist nonetheless, even if Chrome has all necessary permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unfortunate that this device is getting filtered out even though it isn't a location beacon (iBeacon, eddyStone) but this behavior is **currently working as intended** according to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1296054.

Comment: I've contacted the hardware manufacturer already, why the device is identified as iBeacon. Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs/ lists tools and log viewing approaches thay may help, including:

- `chrome://bluetooth-internals`
- [nRF Connect for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp)
- `chrome://device-log`

Try requestDevice with "acceptAllDevices":true as well if you haven't yet.

Comment: Thanks for the Link to chromium.org, it greatly helped find the actual culprit.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the device is not showing up is that Android has a denylist which matches Eddystone and iBeacon payloads using the advertising data.

My device seems to have something in its advertising data which matches Eddystone or iBeacon and thus is ignored, even though it is a digital tape measure.

Sources:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/master/src/com/android/bluetooth/gatt/GattService.java#255
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/master/src/com/android/bluetooth/btservice/AdapterService.java#3939

Comment: It seems like this denyList operates only if the user has denied the  ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION android permission to the Android application (Chrome there).
Can you check your "Location permission" settings for Chrome on Android? Mine for instance have "Use precise location" checked.

Comment: That was my first guess too, but turns out Chrome has already the permissions for precise location and devices near me. And for precise location WiFi and Bluetooth are activated. Maybe Samsung is a bit more restrictive, I'll check with a non-Samsung Android too.

Comment: Seems to be Samsung specific. With a Xiaomi Android phone the device shows up.

Comment: That is interesting! Thanks for sharing Dehalion ;)
Can you reproduce with Samsung Internet Browser by any chance?

Comment: It's the same with Samsung Internet Browser.

Comment: Our of curiosity. which version of Android is it on your Samsung phone?

Comment: My test device runs Android 12 from 2021-12-01, but I have also reports from Samsung Tablets (which I don't know the installed version of).

Comment: It seems like Chromium currently uses "neverForLocation" Android permission flag which tells Android to filter out Eddystone and iBeacon flags. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#assert-never-for-location